# How select value initally when picker view appear?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have set a picker view appearance on text field begin editing function and hide keyboard. Now problem is that when picker view appear then it show selection indicator on first value but that value not show in text field. I want that when user click on text filed then picker view appear and value from picker will show in text field where  selection indicator place. How do that? Suppose i have four value in same order 0,1,2,3. Now when picker view appear then selection indicator is at on '0' value. But to get that value we have to scroll picker view and come back to '0' then it show that value in text field. Why it is occurs? And how get value  automatically?

Thanks in advances...

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no connection between your picker view and the text field - you have to make it yourself.

There are two things to consider:

1) Your text field already contains a value, let's say "1". When you open the picker, you can set it to this value already with the function

`[yourPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:false]`

, assuming your data array for the picker is [0, 1, 2, 3]. In your case, to make the text field contain the value 0, just call

`[textField setText:@"0"]`

2) When you are finished with the picker, it calls the delegate function

`- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`

So you have to make your view implement the **UIPickerViewDelegate** protocol, implement the above delegate function in it and set the view as the picker view's delegate.
In the delegate function you can get the value the user picked (using *row* to access your data array values) and set this value in your textfield.